# Jersey Multipart Form Data Default Value?

Tags: java, rest, jersey, jax-rs, multipartform-data

I have a method that accepts type Multipart Form Data. One of the parameters to this method is a `file` form data param, shown by

```
@FormDataParam("file") InputStream inputStream,
@FormDataParam("file") FormDataContentDisposition contentDispositionHeader
```

I want to be able to hit this endpoint sometimes without providing the form data param `file`, but right now when I leave it out the method returns a 400 bad request immediately. Is there a way I can set it up so that I can leave it out? Or is there some way I can set a default value for this (i.e. to null?). Any help would be appreciated. My method declaration is below:

```
@POST
@Path("/publish")
@Consumes(MediaType.MULTIPART_FORM_DATA)
public Response publish(@Auth Key key,
                        @QueryParam("email") String email,
                        @HeaderParam("password") String password,
                        @QueryParam("type") PublishType type,
                        @QueryParam("message") String message,
                        @FormDataParam("file") InputStream inputStream,
                        @FormDataParam("file") FormDataContentDisposition
                              contentDispositionHeader,
                        @FormDataParam("title") @DefaultValue("") String videoTitle) {
    // code here
}
```

In the end, I want to create an endpoint where a user can publish text to a database, and optionally include an image or some type of media. Let me know if there is another way I can achieve this.

Thank you!

Comment: [I can't reproduce the problem](https://gist.github.com/psamsotha/eb30d0e659a2cb6c09dbcd0d712417ee). What Jersey version are you using?

Comment: @peeskillet I believe I'm using version 2.23.2. But I think the difference in your example might be that you're still posting form data in the request. With mine, when I try to hit the endpoint with no form data at all, only the query params and header params, it returns a 400.

Comment: it doesn't make much sense to put the email and other stuff as query params if it's a POST. why don't you add them as form fields. This is what multipart is meant for.

Comment: @peeskillet I was trying to keep it consistent with other methods I have in the resource where those things are query params. I wanted to keep a consistent API as much as possible

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's not pretty, but the only thing I can think of (if you don't want to post any body), is to use Jersey's `ContainerRequest` that you can inject into the method. Then if there is any body, get the multipart as `FormDataMultiPart` and just traverse the parts manually.

```
@POST
@Produces(MediaType.TEXT_PLAIN)
@Consumes(MediaType.MULTIPART_FORM_DATA)
public String post(@Context ContainerRequest request) {
    final String contentLength = request.getHeaderString(HttpHeaders.CONTENT_LENGTH);
    if (contentLength != null && Integer.parseInt(contentLength) != 0) {
        FormDataMultiPart multiPart = request.readEntity(FormDataMultiPart.class);
        FormDataBodyPart part = multiPart.getField("test");
        String result = part.getValueAs(String.class);
        return result;
    }
    return "no body";
}
```

Below is a complete test

```
import org.glassfish.jersey.client.ClientConfig;
import org.glassfish.jersey.filter.LoggingFilter;
import org.glassfish.jersey.media.multipart.*;
import org.glassfish.jersey.server.ContainerRequest;
import org.glassfish.jersey.server.ResourceConfig;
import org.glassfish.jersey.test.JerseyTest;
import org.junit.Test;

import javax.ws.rs.*;
import javax.ws.rs.client.Entity;
import javax.ws.rs.core.Context;
import javax.ws.rs.core.HttpHeaders;
import javax.ws.rs.core.MediaType;
import javax.ws.rs.core.Response;
import javax.ws.rs.ext.ExceptionMapper;
import java.util.logging.Logger;

import static org.junit.Assert.assertEquals;

/**
 * Example with default value for multipart field.
 *
 * Dependencies for JUnit test.
 *
 *   <dependency>
 *     <groupId>org.glassfish.jersey.test-framework.providers</groupId>
 *     <artifactId>jersey-test-framework-provider-grizzly2</artifactId>
 *     <scope>test</scope>
 *     <version>${jersey2.version}</version>
 *   </dependency>
 *   <dependency>
 *     <groupId>org.glassfish.jersey.media</groupId>
 *     <artifactId>jersey-media-multipart</artifactId>
 *     <version>${jersey2.version}</version>
 *  </dependency>
 */
public class MultiPartMissingTest extends JerseyTest {

    @Path("test")
    public static class TestResource {

        @POST
        @Produces(MediaType.TEXT_PLAIN)
        @Consumes(MediaType.MULTIPART_FORM_DATA)
        public String post(@Context ContainerRequest request) {
            final String contentLength = request.getHeaderString(HttpHeaders.CONTENT_LENGTH);
            if (contentLength != null && Integer.parseInt(contentLength) != 0) {
                FormDataMultiPart multiPart = request.readEntity(FormDataMultiPart.class);
                FormDataBodyPart part = multiPart.getField("test");
                String result = part.getValueAs(String.class);
                return result;
            }
            return "no body";
        }
    }


    @Override
    public ResourceConfig configure() {
        return new ResourceConfig()
                .register(TestResource.class)
                .register(MultiPartFeature.class)
                .register(new LoggingFilter(Logger.getAnonymousLogger(), true))
                .register(new ExceptionMapper<Throwable>() {
                    @Override
                    public Response toResponse(Throwable t) {
                        t.printStackTrace();
                        return Response.serverError().entity(t.getMessage()).build();
                    }
                });
    }

    @Override
    public void configureClient(ClientConfig config) {
        config.register(MultiPartFeature.class);
    }

    @Test
    public void testWithBody() {
        final MultiPart multiPart = new FormDataMultiPart()
                .field("test", "testing");

        final Response response = target("test")
                .request()
                .post(Entity.entity(multiPart, multiPart.getMediaType()));

        assertEquals(200, response.getStatus());
        assertEquals("testing", response.readEntity(String.class));
    }

    @Test
    public void withoutBody() {
        final Response response = target("test")
                .request()
                .post(null);

        assertEquals(200, response.getStatus());
        assertEquals("no body", response.readEntity(String.class));
    }
}
```

Comment: This answers my question, however you're right that it's not very pretty! I may have to rethink my design at this point. Thanks though, this was very informative.

Answer (score 1):

You can simply state that the file param is not required. See below:

```
@POST
@Path("/publish")
@Consumes(MediaType.MULTIPART_FORM_DATA)
public Response publish(
        @Multipart("key") Key key,
        @Multipart(value = "file", required = false) Attachment file) {}
```